# Difference between python's parameters '*', '*args', '**', '**kwargs'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am new to Python and Django framework. I found '*', '*args', '**', '**kwargs' as parameters in init method or in other methods. like given below.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(RestRouter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I am quite unable to understand how to pass these parameters and which one is suitable in which condition? 
Can anyone explain me in brief with a good example for each parameter?

Comment: This is basic python. `*` is not a parameter by the way, it is an operator.

Comment: `*args` is a variable amount of parameters. For example, `fun(*names)` could contain as many names as desired passed in the function like `func('Bob', 'Sam', 'Jon')`.

Comment: Actually I was asking for *params and **params.  I know that * is operator.

Comment: `**kwargs` are keyword parameters in a dictionary format. For example, `fun(**data)` could be `func(name = 'Malik', age = 16)`.

Comment: Do you understand now?

Comment: This link is also very helpful. http://agiliq.com/blog/2012/06/understanding-args-and-kwargs/